# No value given for one or more required parameters while trying to add a record

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to add a new record into a table of the database, based on textbox input. However, I am getting an error:

> No value given for one or more required parameters

I have this code:

```
    private void addWord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(access7ConnectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();

                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Words VALUES(" + "@Name)", conn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Word.Text);
                    int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    //rows number of record got inserted
                }
            }
        }
        catch (OleDbException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

From what I read, ID does not need to be defined if the table's primary key is being auto-incremented. So here is the table in question in Access.

[image]

If I give it the ID parameter, it throws up an error that it cannot allow duplicates. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for your query

```
"INSERT INTO Words (Word) VALUES(?)"
```

This would specifically indicate field to insert into and question mark is a [placeholder for parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2) when dealing with OleDB connection.

Comment: Thanks, that works almost perfectly. The issue is that it takes the word that was in the textbox rather than what was typed. The word loaded by the DB was `autograph` and I typed in `flight`. It inserted `autograph`. How can I fix this?

Comment: What do you mean `loaded by DB`? Does the textbox `Word` originally had text "autograph", you deleted it and typed "flight" instead, then clicked button to submit changes - and it added "autograph" instead?

Comment: I fixed it now. I had the wrong textbox in the code, sorry. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I kinda figured that would be the case :) Glad the solution was helpful